How to blank the view of a .Net MAUI app so it has no view in the list of running apps
I am writing a finance budget app in .Net MAUI.  One of the things I want to try and achieve is when the user navigates away from the app, and then subsequently looks for it again in the list of "currently running" apps it has no view (a bit like the banking apps).  Because the app has users finance details on it, I feel it is right to hide information from anyone until the app is reactivated.
Before anyone asks, code is in place that when the app is reactivated it asks for their a biometric info or PIN confirmation to unlock it.
I have been looking at the available events that can be used in App.xaml but the only one that might help is .Deactivated, which is after the app seems to not respond to be trying to push a (blank) page as the active page.
I have been reading up on the app lifecycle, which doesn't appear to give me the ability to achieve what I need.
Open to ideas how I could achieve this.

have you tried OnBackgrounding?

@Jason - I have previously tried that event, but it never seems to fire for me.

Since you are developing app on iOS, you can try to platform specific code. Add the following code into your MauiProgram.cs:
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                })
                .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
                {
#if IOS || MACCATALYST
#pragma warning disable CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility
                    events.AddiOS(ios => ios
                        .SceneDidEnterBackground((app) => LogEvent(nameof(iOSLifecycle.SceneDidEnterBackground)))
                        .SceneWillEnterForeground((app) => LogEvent(nameof(iOSLifecycle.SceneWillEnterForeground))));
#pragma warning restore CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility
                    static bool LogEvent(string eventName, string type = null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Lifecycle event: {eventName}{(type == null ? string.Empty : $" ({type})")}");
                        if (eventName== "SceneDidEnterBackground")
                        {
                            UIKit.UIViewController blankcontroller = new UIKit.UIViewController();
                            blankcontroller.View.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.White;
                            Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController().PresentViewController(blankcontroller, false, null);
                        }
                        else if (eventName == "SceneWillEnterForeground")
                        {
                            Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController().DismissViewController(false, null);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
#endif
 
                });
             
#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
 
            return builder.Build();
        }
    }

For Android, you can add the following code in your MainActivity.cs:
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
 
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Window?.AddFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            Window?.AddFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
        }
    } 

Update:
Try to use DidEnterBackground | WillEnterForeground:
    .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
         {
#if IOS || MACCATALYST
                    events.AddiOS(ios => ios
                        .OnActivated((app) => LogEvent(nameof(iOSLifecycle.OnActivated)))
                        .OnResignActivation((app) => LogEvent(nameof(iOSLifecycle.OnResignActivation)))
                        .DidEnterBackground((app) => LogEvent(nameof(iOSLifecycle.DidEnterBackground)))
                        .WillEnterForeground((app) => LogEvent(nameof(iOSLifecycle.WillEnterForeground)))
                        .WillTerminate((app) => LogEvent(nameof(iOSLifecycle.WillTerminate))));;
 
             static bool LogEvent(string eventName, string type = null)
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Lifecycle event: {eventName}{(type == null ? string.Empty : $" ({type})")}");
                 if(eventName == "DidEnterBackground") {
 
                     UIKit.UIViewController blankcontroller = new UIKit.UIViewController();
                     blankcontroller.View.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.White;
                     Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController().PresentViewController(blankcontroller, false, null);
 
                 }
                 else if (eventName == "WillEnterForeground")
                 {
                     Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController().DismissViewController(false, null);
                 }
                 else
                 {
 
                 }
 
                 return true;
             }
         });
#endif


Thank you for the suggested code, and I will try that.  I am developing for both iOS and Android, so will this code be sufficient for both?

I updated the answer for Android part, you can try it.

OK, so had a good result for Android - it works as I had hoped, but for iOS when I return to the desktop  and then swipe up to see my active apps, it shows my app screen without being blanked.  When I then select my app to re open it, the first thing it does is show me my "blank security page".

I update the part of iOS, and not use "blank security page" any more. Wish it can help you :)

Unfortunately when I try this on an iOS phone simulator, I can still see my app in the list of open apps, and nothing is blanked out.  It will works well for Android.

For my side, I run it on ios 17.4 phone simulator and it works well. I upadate the answer, you can try two other methods: DidEnterBackground | WillEnterForeground.

That's done it :-) - thank you very much Jianwei Sun.  I am new to Stackoverflow so don't have enough rep points to mark this as an accepted solution, but I wanted to say that here, and say thank you again for your help.

It should be possible. Just click the ✅ as an answer.

As a very quick PoC that I have knocked up you can make use of the App lifecycle events and specifically the Activated and Deactivated events (note that I have only tested this on iOS right now).
Also note that this solution currently assumes that you are using Shell
The steps that I followed are:
1. Create an overlay page
Add a new ContentPage (XAML) and add the overlay view that you would like. The key detail that I have added for now is also the Shell.PresentationMode="Modal" so that this doesn't interfere with the navigation stack.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Shell.PresentationMode="Modal"
             x:Class="MyProject.OverlayPage">
    
    <Label Text="Oh no you don't" 
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    
</ContentPage>

I have omitted the .xaml.cs file purely because I haven't made any changes.
2. Register the route to the new page
Add the routing wherever you like, I just added to MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(OverlayPage), typeof(OverlayPage));

3. Make use of the lifecycle events
Inside the App.xaml.cs file we can override the CreateWindow method to make use of the extra lifecycle events:
protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState? activationState)
{
    Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

    window.Deactivated += async (s, e) =>
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(OverlayPage), false);
    };
    window.Activated += async (s, e) =>
    {
        if (Shell.Current.CurrentPage is OverlayPage)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", false);
        }
    };

    return window;
}

The result is that when the application becomes deactivated the OverlayPage will be shown and when the application becomes Activated the CurrentPage will be hidden if it is of type OverlayPage.
I hope this helps

Thank you for the kind offer of the code, but although it compiled and ran I had the same effect as before - i.e. when I view the app in the list of running apps the last page in the app is still shown.
